# Granular permissions - is partial failure supported?

Tags: google-oauth

As per the move to granular oauth prompts, is it possible that a token will be returned when one or more scopes is rejected by the user?

E.g. request scopes:

- google.com/scope-a
- google.com/scope-b

If the user accepts scope-a but rejects scope-b, will a token still be returned for scope-a only?

Comment: Thats the idea.  Have you tried?